# Android error: Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]

Tags: android, android-studio

When I am trying to run the application on my device instead of Android Virtual Device It gives the error and stops running.

Showing these messages on console.

open: Permission denied
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.sunshine
Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]

$ adb shell pm uninstall com.example.android.sunshine
Unknown failure (Failure)

Comment: Check that you're enabled USB debugging and usb driver for your phone is installed.

Comment: Yes, PC is allowing USB debugging.

Comment: Check whether sufficient memory is there in your mobile phone?

Comment: Device has sufficient amout of memory

Comment: I had the same problem, but I got it working following this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444980/android-install-on-device-failure-install-canceled-by-user)

Comment: I also experienced.. i try set permission folder data/local/tmp

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Additional settings** then select **Install via USB**.

Answer (score 0):

I have also flashed my device with MIUI9 beta ROM and faced this issue. I got a solution to fix this bug.
Download Plex VPN from Playstore and signup.
Select **China - Shenzen** server and hit connect. Once it connected successfully now go to Developer Options and switch to `Install via USB`.

ref. Image:[image: Plex VPN Screen]