# Can't install Android APK from ADB on Xaomi Redmi Note 4

Tags: android, adb

Anyone else have one of the latest Xaomi Redmi phones? My Note 4 just won't let me compile and deploy an APK from Android Studio:

```
04/18 21:08:14: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\martin\Documents\Android Projects\test-android\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.test.app

$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.test.app"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.test.app
Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]

$ adb shell pm uninstall com.test.app
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APK
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer from @Yury Bragin 
from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641670/adb-install-failure-install-canceled-by-user)

- Go to the "Security" application and tap "Options" at top right corner
- Scroll down to "Feature Settings" group, and look for "Permissions"
- At there switch off "Install via USB" option, which manages installation of the apps via USB and doesn't allow it

Answer (score 1):

Now in updated MIUI 8 in Xaomi Redmi Note 4, "Install via USB" is moved to "developer option".
So go to setting => additional Settings => Developer Options => update "Install via USB".

Few more details in blog: [click here](http://sforsuresh.in/xiaomi-mi-note-4-install-via-usb-device-temporarily-restricted/)