# Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER] error installing app on Xiaomi redmi note 2

Tags: android, android-studio

I have android version 5.0.2 LRX22G. MIUI version 8 Global 6.10.27| Beta
I have read some things online but they didn't seem to work for me. Help?

```
 11/03 11:15:19: Launching app
 $ adb push C:\Users\Bozo\AndroidStudioProjects\App2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.amplitudo.app2
 $ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.amplitudo.app2"
 pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.amplitudo.app2
 Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]
```

Comment: during this a popup appears on your phone where you must allow installation

Comment: I didn't get a popup on my phone.

Comment: For error with MIUI 8 -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444980/android-install-on-device-failure-install-canceled-by-user/41298306#41298306