# Android Studio is unable to install my APK

Tags: android, download, apk

Error below

```
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APK
```

Below which I have tried for solving this issues. All of these are not working.

- I have tried changing the package name.
- I have tried clean project.
- I have tried manually delete the app on the device.

In order to run the apk on the device, I need to download the apk by copy and paste the apk to a folder in the device and install from there.

Other weird things are. Only happen one of my device. I can download the apk to another device just fine.

Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Build > Clean Project`. Uninstall old .Run Again

Comment: if you have multiple user enabled, then uninstall app from all users

Comment: Refresh your gradle. Clean project alone wont solve the issue.Click on the gradle tab on Android studio. And click the gradle refresh button.

Comment: refresh on gradle tried, not working. May i know how to uninstall app from all users. I suspect the problem is on the device settings. since only this device which installation failed.

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya Build>Clean, tried. not working.

Comment: @amalBit refresh on gradle tried, not working.

Comment: @Divyesh how to uninstall app from all users. I don't even know the device supports multiple users. Thanks.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/92130/36758

Comment: @amalBit  do you mean google account? i check the device, only have one google account.

Comment: No , if the phone has multiple user profile. Uninstalling them for different profile is tricky. as @Divyesh has pointed out.

Comment: use ADB to complete uninstall app from device

Comment: @Divyesh I tried adb uninstall com.xxx.yyy   (my package name)  result--> adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
Success
then the error still there. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on my xiaomi device, it auto update to new version, all of sudden the enable of install via USB required to sign in Mi account.

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444980/android-install-on-device-failure-install-canceled-by-user)