# error while loading app on phone from android studio

Tags: android, failed-installation

hi I am new to app programing, I have a Redmi 1s phone. so to load my app fro android studio I connected y phone and clicked the play button. everything looked good but the app didn't install giving the following error.
if the app is already there uninstall it, even though this was the first time I clicked play, any how I clicked on uninstall and checked the error report I showed me this .

```
06/19 10:36:55: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\ubrbcca\AndroidStudioProjects\HAPPYBIRTHDAYAADHYA\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.happybirthdayaadhya
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.happybirthdayaadhya"
open: Permission denied
open: Permission denied
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.happybirthdayaadhya
Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]


Error while Installing APK
```

plz help me out

Comment: Please show the build.gradle file from the app module of your project.

Comment: What is the app you are trying to install? Have you written much code? I suggest starting a new project with a simple activity and trying to run it on your phone without changing any of the code which Android Studio generates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29444980/5324829

Comment: I have had the similar problem with Xoami. Turn off instant run and try again.

Comment: thank u all for ur response, its working

Answer (score 1):

Check the followings:

Go to Settings -> Permissions -> Install via USB: Uncheck your App if it's listed.

Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Privacy: Check the Unknown Sources option.

Finally go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options: Check the Install via USB option.

And

Turn off Miui Optimizations on Developer Settings, then Restart the phone.