# Oppo - Failed to install *.apk: Failure [-99]

Tags: android, adb, oppo

When I try to install an apk through ADB In an Oppo R11 (version : R11_11A, Android 7)it fails:

> adb install MyApp.apk
>
> Failed to install MyApp.apk: Failure [-99]

A login screen shows up. Is this the same as the Xiaomi MIUI 8 problem? not allowing Installing apk's with no account?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41298306/7500344

Comment: You should enable developer mode from mobile setting

Comment: I did enabled developer. turned on debugging, turned on Install Unknown Source Apps

Comment: try downgrading buildToolsVersion to "23.0.0"

Comment: I had the same problem as you. I cleaned the project and removed app in Oppo. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

you should add this line `android.injected.testOnly=false` to your `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all install **Oppo driver** in PC

Turn on **developer mode**

And after that scroll down to **Turn on USB debugging**

Comment: thank you for the reply, I don't have an Oppo to test the solution on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when trying to install android project on Chinese phones such as huawei, oppo, xiaomi etc.

After turning on developers mode and USB debugger mode on your phone, and adding all firebase required json file, SHA1, dependencies etc, to your project ,

First, you must register your fingerprint unlock mode to your phone. if your phone doesn't have fingerprint unlock mode, you must set password unlock mode. Anytime you try to install a project, it requires you to unlock the phone to allow instalation.