# Hello World Android project is not installing in REDMi Note 5

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have prepared a new android development setup in my **windows 7 64-Bit** machine.

**Android Studio Version:** 3.5.3

**JDK:** 1.8.0_231

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**AndroidManufest.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I install the APK file generated after compilation in emulator (Nexus 6P API 27 x86) it works fine. However, when I am trying to install the same APK file in my phone its not installing. I have already deactivated **Play Protect** options.

Comment: Did you install the app using android run button or generated APK from output folder? Did you get any error? If yes please add it.

Comment: @AliSadeghi I have generated build file (app-debug.apk) and then placed in mobile download directory and installing it from there.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41298306/3892248)?

Comment: in Mi you need to signin into MI account for installing apps, even after enabling developer optinos

Comment: @ked Already signed in, No Luck :(

Comment: Post the screen shot while failed to install

Comment: @Saddan Issue is resolve, please have a look on the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

disable wifi and mobile data and get build then install apk on your phone
i seen this issue in my app and It looks like google protect stuff

Comment: Did not work even after disabling WiFi and mobile data.

Answer (score -1):

```
 debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Solved my problem.